# App creation failed: Please use your personal account to create this app

Tags: facebook, creation

I'm trying to create an Facebook app for mobile but I'm getting "App creation failed
Please use your personal account to create this app. To use a different name for testing, create the app with your personal account and then create a test account." Does anyone have any ideas as this has brought me to a standstill (my Facebook account has been verified) ?

Comment: Are you using your personal account for development?

Comment: Thanks for for quick reply - yes, its a personal account.

Comment: You can try submitting an appeal at https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=140703502680919 ...

Comment: facing the same issue .. any luck ??/

Comment: Cheers, I'll do that and update this with the results!

Comment: Are you sure it's your (real, only, verified) personal user account?

Comment: looks like my account was blocked - not sure why I wasn't getting the 'blocked' message when trying to create the app though...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Comment: @Andy Beard, has your problem resolved?

Comment: @Andy Beard I am having the same issues.. Can you please tell me if this has been solved? If yes, can you add how you solved it? thanks..